# Axios Error on file upload from react to flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios

I'm trying to upload a CSV File from React to my Flask backend. My code is shown below. With the code below, the Flask returns 400 (Axios Error).

When I change the Flask to `print(request.files)`, it prints `ImmutableDict([])` and it doesn't seem to have any data (I think so..)

Error:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpReques
```

App.js:

```
    let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let file = csvFile
        const formData = new FormData()

        formData.append("file", file)

        axios
            .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/reactTest", formData)
            .then((res) => console.log(res))
            .catch((err) => console.warn(err))

...

<input 
type='file'
value={csvFile}
name='csvFile'
/>
<button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}></button>
```

api.py:

```
@app.route('/reactTest', methods=['POST'])
def reactTest():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(request.files)
        print(request.files['file'])
        return {'status': 200}
```

Comment: What does the response body look like? Try logging `err.response.data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="file">` cannot be a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) because you cannot set the `value` due to browser security restrictions.

Instead, treat it as an uncontrolled component. You can even just pass an `HTMLFormElement` into `FormData` to capture all inputs.

```jsx
const [hasFiles, setHasFiles] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target); // pass the entire form

  try {
    console.log(await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/reactTest", formData));
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err.toJSON());
  }
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="file"
      name="file"
      onChange={(e) => setHasFiles(e.target.files.length > 0)}
    />
    <button type="submit" disabled={!hasFiles}>
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
);
```

Note the file input's name is now *"file"* to match the field you want in `FormData`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header for the request to be recognized as containing file:

```
let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData()

    formData.append("file", file)

    axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/reactTest", formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        })
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => console.warn(err))

...
```

Comment: Setting this manually is usually a mistake